# Displaying results as single row

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm stuck. The simpliest way to describe my problem will be uploading a screenshot ;)

[Absences - index.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V8ga.png)

I am implementing absences system. These red badges are displaying when student was absent, and the grey display when student was present.

I want to display these three rows as a single row, because they have the same "created_at" field, but to be honest, I have no idea how to do it. So help me, if you can of course :)

It's my source code:

(CreateAbsencesTable.php)

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('absences', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('teacher_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('lesson')->unsigned();
        $table->string('status');
        $table->string('comment')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

(AbsenceController@index)

```
    /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    if (auth()->user()->hasRole('student')) {
        $absences = Absence::orderBy('created_at')->where('student_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();

        // dd($absences);

        return view('absences.index', compact('absences'));
    }
}
```

(resources/views/absences/index.blade.php)

```
                    @role('student')
                    <table class="table table-borderless table-striped shadow-lg mb-5">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="align-middle pl-3 w-25">{{ __('Date') }}</th>
                                <th class="align-middle pl-3">{{ __('Lesson') }}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($absences as $absence)
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="align-middle pl-4 w-25">{{ $absence->created_at }}</td>
                                    <td class="align-middle pl-4">
                                        @for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++)
                                            @if ($i == $absence->lesson)
                                                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger my-second-badge">
                                                    {{ $i }}
                                                </span>
                                            @else
                                                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary my-second-badge">
                                                    {{ $i }}
                                                </span>
                                            @endif
                                        @endfor
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                @endrole
```

Thanks for help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in Controller in `index()` action u need to group $absences by `created_at`

```
public function index()
{
    if (auth()->user()->hasRole('student')) {
        return view('absences.index', [
            'absences' => Absence::orderBy('created_at')->where('student_id', auth()->user()->id)->get()->groupBy('created_at')
        ]);
    }
}
```

after in blade.php run by `$absences`

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($absences as $date => $absence)
    <tr>
        <td class="align-middle pl-4 w-25">{{ $date }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle pl-4">
            @for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++)
                @if ($absence->contains($id))
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger my-second-badge">
                                                    {{ $i }}
                                                </span>
                @else
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary my-second-badge">
                                                    {{ $i }}
                                                </span>
                @endif
            @endfor
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Now i can display it as a single row, but I cannot also use $absence->created_at. And all of seeded data displays on the first, which is also the last row. So an absence added yesterday displays with the absences added today, if you know what I mean :D

Comment: okey, u need to `groupBy(created_at)`, and after, u need to use `@foreach`

Comment: `$absences = Absence::orderBy('created_at')->where('student_id', auth()->user()->id)->get()->groupBy('created_at');`

Comment: I wasn't replying because of try of implementing that. I've got the same query as you wrote in the last post, i had to change in config/database.php 'strict' to false, but now I am getting an error "array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer" when I use this: "$absences = Absence::orderBy('created_at')->where('student_id', auth()->user()->id)->get()->groupBy('created_at');"

Comment: And also when I'm using groupBy('created_at') before get() method, the variable is getting all results for a student, but not grouped.

Comment: u need to use it after, i have fix my main comment

Comment: I feel we are close, good man. But i am still getting an error "array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer" on the line, when I use "->groupBy('created_at')", but I don't know why :/

Comment: wait, I start my project and chack this example)) 4 min

Comment: I really appreciate it, Bohdan :)

Comment: your timestamp fiels is autocasting in laravel, thats why we have a problems https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators.  In   Absence model add property  `public $timestamps = false;`

Comment: but I think it will better if u add new table in migration `$table->date('date');` and will work with this table )as u see it will be much easily

Comment: I don't know how you did that, they are grouped. It won't work for me haha

Comment: Bohdan, an idea with another column in table was perfect! I really thank you for solving my problem. I wish you best!